# Kendo grid Format number with whitespace as thousand separator and two decimal places

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I need to format numbers in a column with white space as thousand separator and with two decimal places. For example: 125895456.8942 -> 125 895 456.89

```
 columns: [
      {
            field: "sumStartDebit",
            title: "Debit",
            width: "130px",
            template: function (dataItem) {
                if (dataItem.sumStartDebit == 0) { return "" }
                else if (dataItem.sumStartDebit < 0) { return "<span style='color:red'>" + dataItem.sumStartDebit + "</span>" }
                else { return "<span>" + dataItem.sumStartDebit + "</span>" }
                    },
            locked: true,
             },
          ]
```

What can i achieve it w/o culture? I have a function that works for thousand separator but not for my condition of two decimal places

```
function numberWithSpaces(x) {
            return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ");
        }
```

Comment: are you looking for a function to split up each number in the way you want?

Comment: Hi, yes. I think that a function is a good idea. I have updated my question to show what function i've used

Comment: does every number come in like your example? so its like 340934209.0025 ? so there is always 4 decimal places

Comment: Unfortunately no. The number can come with two, three decimal places

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
function numberWithSpaces(x) {
        return kendo.toString(x, "##,#.##").replace(/,/g, " ")
}
```

You format your string with the usual decimal seperator in your culture (in this case "," for en-US) and then replace that with a whitespace using regex.
For "12345678.0394" you would get  "12 345 678.04"

You could inline this inside your template as well:

```
template: '#= kendo.toString(sumStartDebit, "##,#.##").replace(/,/g, " ")#'
```